# Redirect subfolder requests to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a setup where I can only access the root of a domain (subdomains are not allowed due to restrictive firewall policies). Lets say the domain is `www.domain.com`, for testing i have a symlinked a folder in `/var/www/testing` that points to several html and css files. In these files, scripts and css are included like e.g.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">`

which will fail as apache looks for the file in `www.domain.com/css/app.css` while it resides in `www.domain.com/testing/css/app.css` is there a possibility with .htaccess or RewriteEngine to make all requests (for css and js files) coming from `/testing/` also going to `/testing/...` like examplified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RedirectMatch ^/(css/.+\.css)$ /testing/$1
```

This will redirect /css/file.css to /testing/css/file.css

Comment: cool. that works fine. do you also know how to condition the rule to only match requests that themselves come from `testing`?